# get topic of sentence from pre-trained model

Tags: nlp, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

I have a list of 10 sentences from a text file.
I want to use an existing topics model to get the topics of every sentence.

In all the tutorials I found - they trained the topic model on their corpus. I want to use one that was trained in existing corpus and just apply it on my sentences.

Is this possible?

Comment: I can't escape the feeling that this question belongs more to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) SO community than StackOverflow...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible as long as the language of your sentences matches the language of the corpus and, to a smaller degree, as long as the vocabulary of both intersect (particularly among the most distinctive words for each of the topics). Also, if there is a large divergence between human topics of your sentences and those captured in the corpus then you may end up with a not clear attribution of topics to sentences (e.g. neither of the topics will be found particularly similar to a sentence or to put it differently: all will be similar but degree of similarity will be small for all of them).

I encourage you to reuse the models you can find with the sentences you have and see experimentally if they work for you as expected.

Comment: Show us the code you tried so that we could help you (see: [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ).

Comment: I haven't try any way to do it beside downloading mallet, but I want to use a pythoon-package and not have to install softwares